# Chess challenge #7: Women's European Team Championship

Tags: tactics, problems, women

In the recent Women's European Team Championship Anna Muzychuk won a quick game against Almira Skripchenko.

```
[fen "r3qrk1/1b3ppp/ppp5/2nBp1N1/P3P3/7P/1PP1QPP1/R2R2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Skripchenko has just played 15 ... c6 and resigned a few moves later because of a beautiful tactical sequence played by Muzychuk. **How did White win the game?**

Comment: is 'resigned a few moves later' kind of a big hint? idk. but definitely a good share. Anna Muzychuk is definitely up there with Judit Polgar, Humpy Koneru, Hou Yifan and Ju Wenjun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the winning tactical combination is the following:

> 1.Qh5! h6 2.Bxf7+ Rxf7 3.Qxf7+ Qxf7 4.Nxf7 Kxf7 5.b4 Nxe4 6.Rd7+

Comment: and to think the game is kinda even if only the bishop weren't hanging!